# How to convert while loop with arrays in C to ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I'm currently learning ARM and I have to convert a particular C snippet into ARM code to test on the machine. However, I don't know how to declare array in ARM specifically and I didn't find very relevant resources that explained it..

```
i = 0
while (i < 0xB) {
    x[i] = i*2;
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is C for ARM.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: The C code can be very well compiled for arm as is. Not speaking of a fact there is no `**` operator in C (or at least it is not doing what you think it is).

Comment: What did you find when you compiled it.  EVERYTHING you need to know about this is very easy to find on the internet BTW...

Comment: there is no such thing as an array in assembly language

Comment: I did not find any way to represent arrays in ARM language on the internet..

Comment: If you want to see what ARM code your C code translates into, use a compiler.  If you are trying to do the translation yourself, then you'll need a lot more help than just how to declare an array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. where I can I compile this code from C into ARM? Is there an online compiler?

Comment: "I don't know how to declare array **due to lack of information on the internet.**" - You are kidding, are you? Your teacher should have given you all information, too. If not, ask him to improve the course material.

Comment: You are lucky today. https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you and god bless you sir. You just got me a B from a C in a subject I detest

Comment: @EugeneSh.: See? Helping people to cheat their exams is a really bad idea. Do you want to have a co-worker permanently asking to do his job?Let's hope the tutor know stack overflow. Would not be the first exam failed due to cheating.

Comment: @Olaf Not that I solved something for him (her?) . Just pointed to an openly available tool which I've discovered on SO myself.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I strongly assume the assignment was to manually translate, which is a vital task learning Assembly language, every programmer should have learned in the first place.

Comment: @Olaf When the teacher doesn't give you any notes/reference material, doesn't take any classes and gives you assignments for the sake of updating marks, it isn't the students fault. Kinly don't be presumptuous. I used the tool pointed out by Eugene and learnt from it

Comment: @Solly: 1) Change course then or complain at the school/university. 2) You talk to an autodidact who learned all this **without** the web even existing and no access to the internet that time and no experts to ask. **You** have the resources available at your fingertips. So yes, my comment is well justified! As a friendly advice: Spoon-feeding is nothing which will get you anywhere in your life, less in programming, etc. Learn to search for yourself first.

Comment: @Olaf You probably had a lot more time back then and this course meant something to you. In my country, you can't just *drop* a course because you don't like it. It's a program core course. As for spoonfeeding etc etc, I'm ranked yellow on Topcode and landed an internship at Facebook this summer as a ukrainian. You're probably really good at embedded systems whereas I detest. I don't have/want to allocate my energy to this. That's just the way it is. Thanks for the advice, even though I live by it mostly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, there is not answer to this question, I'm just going to use [GodBolt](http://godbolt.org) and input the OP's code there.

I'm taking the liberty of formatting the given code as so:

```
void assign(int num) {
    int x[10];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 0xB) {
        x[i] = i*2;
    }
}
```

The compiler used to translate this is **ARM gcc 5.4.1**

Translated Code:

```
assign(int):
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!
        add     fp, sp, #0
        sub     sp, sp, #60
        str     r0, [fp, #-56]
        mov     r3, #0
        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
.L3:
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
        cmp     r3, #10
        bgt     .L4
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
        mov     r2, r3, asl #1
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
        mov     r3, r3, asl #2
        sub     r1, fp, #4
        add     r3, r1, r3
        str     r2, [r3, #-44]
        b       .L3
.L4:
        mov     r0, r0    @ nop
        sub     sp, fp, #0
        ldr     fp, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
```

Source: https://godbolt.org/g/5Tv3gk

Comment: Thanks, I guess this question is formally closed as it since I got the answer from the comments from Olaf

Answer (score 1):

Just write the code in C and let the compiler translate it to ARM assembly. Then inspect the generated code.